# Nested if statements that return boolean in prolog

Tags: if-statement, prolog

I want to compare two `date` structures that return `true` if the first date is earlier than the second one, and `false` otherwise.

The logic is simple.

Let the first date D1, and second date D2.

1. If year of D1 > year of D2, return `false`.
2. If year of D1 == year of D2, compare month.
3. If year of D1 < year of D2, return `true`.

This process is repeated till the comparison of seconds.

Sample code I tried:

```
date_earlier_than(date(SY, SM, SD, SH, SMm, SS, _, _, _),
                  date(EY, EM, ED, EH, EMm, ES, _, _, _)) :-
    (   SY > EY ->
        fail
    ;
        SY =:= EY ->
            (   SM > EM ->
                fail
            ;
                SM =:= EM ->
                    (   SD > ED ->
                        fail
                    ;
                        SD =:= ED ->
                            (   SH > EH ->
                                fail
                            ;
                                SH =:= EH ->
                                    (   SMm > EMm ->
                                        fail
                                    ;
                                        SMm =:= EMm ->
                                            (   SS >= ES ->
                                                fail
                                            ;
                                                true
                                            )
                                    ;
                                        true
                                    )
                            ;
                                true
                            )
                    ;
                        true
                    )
            ;
                true
            )
    ;
        true
    ).
```

This predicate always returns `false` whatever dates passed as arguments.

I don't know where it goes wrong, and even if I use `trace` to keep track of the process, the predicate immediately returns `false` after the execution.

**UPDATE**:

The sample code works as expected, but I did not use `date/9` when I tested it, leading to failure.

Here's revised form:

```
date_earlier_than(date(SY, SM, SD, SH, SMm, SS, SOff, STZ, SDST),
                  date(EY, EM, ED, EH, EMm, ES, EOff, ETZ, EDST)) :-
    Start = date(SY, SM, SD, SH, SMm, SS, SOff, STZ, SDST),
    End = date(EY, EM, ED, EH, EMm, ES, EOff, ETZ, EDST),
    Start @< End, !.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all completely unnecessary.

If you represent the date as a compound term, those will compare correctly using the built-in comparison predicates and the "standard order of terms". See for example the SWI-Prolog docs:

https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=standardorder

or GNU-Prolog:

http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec77

Try, for example:

```
?- date(2020, 10, 26, 10, 34, 43) @< date(2020, 10, 26, 6, 34, 43).
```

or:

```
?- date(2020, 10, 26, 10, 34, 43) @> date(2020, 10, 26, 6, 34, 43).
```

But this is also not necessary. Just represent your time as a timestamp (seconds since 1970-01-01T0:0:0Z, for example) and compare those as numbers (probably floats). See for example here:

https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=timedate

Comment: I also tried using `@<` but it failed to evaluate `date` in the form of variables. So are there no ways of getting the result of nested `if` (assuming date is not the case)?

Comment: @PHD of course there is way to make a nested if. But not sure what you are now asking exactly. Maybe you can nest only twice in your question so that it is obvious where is the mistake. I also do not understand what you mean by "failed to evaluate date in the form of variables". Can you show that in code?

Comment: Ok, I will narrow it down. For the failure of evaluation, I meant the following code: `get_time(TimeStamp), current_prolog_flag(timezone, TZ), stamp_date_time(TimeStamp, Date, TZ), Date @< date(2021,
10, 26).` which evaluates to `false`. That may be due to the comparison between atom and compound term.

Comment: @PHD This query you have in the comment has nothing to do with the question. Anyway, drop the last comparison from your query so that you see what `Date` looks like. I see: `Date = date(2020, 10, 26, 14, 36, 58.586801052, -7200, -, -).` So indeed, if you try to compare the atom `-` using arithmetic comparison, this will fail.

Comment: @PHD ... but in the query you show in your comment, `Date` is a compound term with arity 9; it will always be "greater" than a compound term with arity 3. From the docs (link in my answer: "Compound terms are first checked on their arity..."

Answer (score 1):

> This predicate always returns false whatever dates passed as arguments.

Not for me:

```
?- Today = date(2020, 10, 26, 12, 13, 14, _, _, _), Agincourt = date(1415, 10, 25, 09, 10, 11, _, _, _), date_earlier_than(Today, Agincourt).
false.

?- Today = date(2020, 10, 26, 12, 13, 14, _, _, _), Agincourt = date(1415, 10, 25, 09, 10, 11, _, _, _), date_earlier_than(Agincourt, Today).
Today = date(2020, 10, 26, 12, 13, 14, _2890, _2892, _2894),
Agincourt = date(1415, 10, 25, 9, 10, 11, _2916, _2918, _2920).
```

The battle of Agincourt did indeed take place before today, so your predicate seems to be working, at least to some extent. This is a good argument for always (**always**) including your test data in your questions.

Other than that, I agree with the other answer's suggestion of setting your data up such that you can just use `@<` to compare them. I don't necessarily agree with the other answer's suggesion of using an opaque seconds-since-epoch representation. It depends on what you actually need to do, and if it has to take time zones into account.

Comment: I was fool. I used `date/3` for the arguments. After I tested using `date/9`, the predicate works. The answer was there, and I didn't put the right values into it!

Comment: Even if you take time zones in account, it is easier to keep it as a pair of universal time (in some format) and a time zone. The local time can be extracted from these.

Comment: It is altogether dangerous to use free variables when comparing. On my computer, this succeeds: `?- X = date(2020, 10, _), Y = date(2020, 10, _), X @< Y.` (what?) and this fails: `?- X = date(2020, 10, _), Y = date(2020, 10, _), X == Y.` (what???)

Comment: Agreed about the variables, one should definitely completely remove any fields one doesn't need.